# How to create a command using multiple options in JDA?

Tags: discord-jda

I wanted to create a `nick` command, however, I don't know how to add multiple options. The method `addOption()` just adds one.

```
event.getGuild().upsertCommand("nick", "Change the nickname of the specified user").addOption(OptionType.USER,"nicknameuser", "Specified User", true).queue();
```

Comment: Just call addOption again?

Comment: @Minn what do you mean with calling addOption again? Nvm I'm stupid

Answer (score 0):

How about to call addOption again after using addOption?

```
event.getGuild().upsertCommand("nick", "Change the nickname of the specified user")
  .addOption(OptionType.USER, "nicknameuser", "Specified User", true)
  .addOption(OptionType.STRING, "search", "Search the user with a string", true)
  .queue();
```

like this